# Bullets not displaying on dd tag when display is set to list-item

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I cannot get bullets to display using the  tag when I have explicitly set the display to list-item and the list-style-type to square (disc didn't work either)

CSS:

```
#page1 dd
{

    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

HTML:

```
      <dl>

        <dt>How does the game work? </dt>           
        <dd>It provides a process - a way to ask questions and find consensus-building answers through an interactive, web-based simulation.</dd>
        <dd>It creates a common language for discussing issues. </dd>
        <dd>It moves the conversation from an individual view to a systemic one. </dd>
      </dl>
```

Here is what it looks like in the browser.  Any ideas as to what may be interfering with the code - in firebug it shows it to be applying correctly, but the effect is not visible.

[image: this is what it looks like in the browser]

Comment: Perhaps this would have better been marked up as a heading followed by an unordered list. `dt` isn't quite intended for headings or titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to give some margin for the bullets to show up:

http://jsfiddle.net/BPMWP/2/

```
dd {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left:20px;
    }
```

The `display:list-item` property doesn't have the default css that a `ul` or `ol` would have, so it hides the bullets unless you expressly indent the items.

This was actually a huge pain to figure out. Inspecting the element [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#listitem) is what solved it for me. Good question!

Comment: Is the jsfiddle showing that correctly? They seem to work without the margin for me? http://benjaminhopkins.co.uk/stackoverflow/dlexample.html Maybe the OP has set padding/margin 0 for body tag?

Comment: There's a good chance there is some css to the effect of dd{margin:0} somewhere in her code(perhaps in a reset stylesheet). There is 40px of default left-margin for dd tags that is not appearing in her screenshot.

Comment: Yeah id guess so, just concerned that they don't display in jsfiddle without the margin :/

Comment: Thanks!  I had just worked on a line with an image to the left and saw the bullet inside the image - so I was inadvertently working myself to the same answer.